# Problema com Mascara Moeda e calculo

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho uma função que é chamada aqui:

```
 $("#valorPrimeiroPedido").focusout(function () {
        var valor = $("#valorPrimeiroPedido").val();
        calcularValorMercadoria(valor);      
    });
```

`$("#valorPrimeiroPedido").val()` já me traz o valor formatado *(ex:R$:1.500,56)*. Quando perde o foco ele chama a função abaixo, passando o valor formatado. Ai está o erro. Não consigo calcular o IPI e mostrar no *HTML*.

```
 function calcularValorMercadoria(valor) {

            var _valorPedido = CurrencyFormat(valor);
            var _valorPedidoComIPI = _valorPedido * 1.1;

            console.log(_valorPedido);
            $("#ipi").html("Valor do pedido com IPI: R$ " + CurrencyFormat(_valorPedidoComIPI));
        }
```

> ```
> Erro: Uncaught ReferenceError: *CurrencyFormat is not defined*.
> ```

Quando eu tiro a mascara `CurrencyFormat`, o valor retornado é: `R$ NaN`

Estou usando algumas bibliotecas:

```
<script src="~/Content/modalAjax/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/modalAjax/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.maskedinput.js"></script>
<script src="~/Areas/Representantes/Script/cliente/cadastro.js"></script>
<script src="~/Areas/Representantes/Script/cliente/abas.js"></script>
<link href="~/Areas/Representantes/Script/cliente/ClienteEstilo.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Content/modalAjax/bootstrapcdn.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/modalAjax/ajaxmodaldeconfirmacaobootbox.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/plentz/jquery-maskmoney/master/dist/jquery.maskMoney.min.js"></script>
```

**Resumo:** Eu preciso pegar o valor no formato Real, calcular o IPI e mostrar o calculo também no formato Real e depois salvar no formato *float* (no SQL).

Comment: É preciso usar o `replace` para remover o `R$` e substituir a vírgula pelo ponto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É necessário remover alguns caracteres como letras e vírgulas para poder realizar cálculos no *JavaScript*.

Como você está usando a biblioteca `jquery.maskMoney.min.js`, basta utilizar a evento `unmask`. Este evento irá retornar os valore sem os caracteres supracitados, por exemplo:

```
'R$ 1.234,56' => 1234.56
```

Dessa forma, o *JavaScript* irá conseguir converter para um valor númerico e assim poderá realizar o cálculo.

**Exemplo comentado:**

```js
/* Aplica a máscara no campo */
$(function() {
  $('#valorPrimeiroPedido').maskMoney({
    prefix: 'R$ ',
    thousands: '.',
    decimal: ','
  });
})

/* Calcula o valor da mercadoria */
$("#valorPrimeiroPedido").focusout(function() {

  /* Captura o valor sem máscara (sem o R$) */
  let valor = $('#valorPrimeiroPedido').maskMoney("unmasked")[0];

  calcularValorMercadoria(valor);
});

/* Função para calcular o valor da mercadoria */
function calcularValorMercadoria(_valorPedido) {
  let _valorPedidoComIPI = _valorPedido * 1.1;

  console.log(_valorPedido);
  $("#ipi").html("Valor do pedido com IPI: R$ " + CurrencyFormat(_valorPedidoComIPI));
}

/* Função para retornar os valores com "máscara" */
function CurrencyFormat(value) {
  return new Number(value).toLocaleString("ptb",{
    style: "currency",
    currency: "BRL"
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/plentz/jquery-maskmoney/master/dist/jquery.maskMoney.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="valorPrimeiroPedido" />

<span id="ipi"></span>
```

---

Sobre o erro abaixo

> ```
> Uncaught ReferenceError: CurrencyFormat is not defined.
> ```

O erro abaixo acontece pois a função `CurrencyFormat` não foi criada.

Comment: Muito obrigada, é isso mesmo.. funcionou

Comment: estranho, fiz o mesmo código alterando nome de variável e aparece aqui: TypeError: numer01.maskMoney is not a function